# Line breaks for items while wrapping images with a list

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, itemize, wrapfig

I am trying to create a list with figure on the right side in beamer but the sentence breaks at unusual places.

```
    \begin{frame}{Protocol}
            \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.2\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Schematic_coating}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        \noindent
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Prepare 0.6 M NaCl solution in a 10 mM Tris-HCl (pH 8.5) solution
                \item Clean the glass substrate using ultrasonication with water and acetone or ethanol.
                \item Leave the substrate for 8 h into the solution for coating.
                \item Rinse extensively with ultrapure water and dry under a stream of nitrogen.
            \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image: Image showing line break]

Comment: What is the specific question? Is it about how to manually insert a line break, or how to shift the "automatic" layout or something else?

Comment: Why not use the columns environment instead of trying to make wrapfig work here?

Comment: I am not that much accustomed to the Latex environment. Just started using it for presentation and articles. Using columns somehow didn't occur to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible layout using `columns`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % do not use the demo option in your actual document.
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Protocol}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Prepare 0.6 M NaCl solution in a 10 mM Tris-HCl (pH 8.5) solution
        \item Clean the glass substrate using ultrasonication with water and acetone or ethanol.
        \item Leave the substrate for 8 h into the solution for coating.
        \item Rinse extensively with ultrapure water and dry under a stream of nitrogen.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Schematic_coating}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. This is what I needed.